# Xamarin forms Loading Spinner without button action

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to make a loading spin in Xamarin forms. After the login screen, the webview on the main screen takes about 3 seconds to load, at that time I want to have a loading spin.I tried using the acr.userdialogs package but I could only trigger it with a button.
my goal is to work for 3 seconds from the moment the page is opened (without triggering it with a button or something like that.) how can i do that? thanks.

**EDIT :** **(In the code I shared, I can trigger it with the login button, but my aim is to do it without triggering it with a button on the main page.)**

`async void btnLoginClick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

```
        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {

            var userName = tbName.Text;
            var password = tbPassword.Text;

            var serviceUrl = "API";

            var paramList = new List<ServiceParameterObject>();
            paramList.Add(new ServiceParameterObject("_userCode", userName));
            paramList.Add(new ServiceParameterObject("_userPassword", password));

            var apiResult = ApiResult.SendPostRequestFromBody(serviceUrl, paramList);



            if (apiResult.Status)
            {
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiResult.Message);

                //Preferences.Set("userName", tbName.Text);
                //Preferences.Set("Password", tbPassword.Text);
                Preferences.Set("userId", user.Id.ToString());

                var userIdCookie = Preferences.Get("userId", String.Empty);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomeScreen()); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Yukleniyor...",MaskType.Black);

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "Kullanıcı Adınız veya Şifreniz hatalıdır. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.", "Tamam");
            }`
```

Comment: FYI: I see you've solved it, but it looks like this has been asked and answered before: [xamarin.forms loading indicator not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002729/xamarin-forms-loading-indicator-not-showing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class HomeScreen : ContentPage
{   
    public HomeScreen ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        


            var userIdCookie = Preferences.Get("userId", String.Empty);

        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            
            //_userCode = Encrytpion.EncryptString(_userCode,"1234567812345678");



            OneSignal.Default.SetExternalUserId(userIdCookie);

            webView.Source = "wvsource";

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Yukleniyor...", MaskType.Black);

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            });

        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "İnternet bağlantınız yok. Lütfen Bağlantınızı kontrol edip tekrar deneyiniz", "Tamam");
        }
    }
```

i did it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).